# Change a property of each project in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, cmake-gui

I have a big solution with many projects. I want to change the `Windows SDK Version` property for each project but without going through every single one and setting it manually.

The solution is created with `cmake-gui` from an open source CMake-based framework, i.e. [AliceVision](https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the variable setting in a file (with anything else shared) and then include that into each project's make file.

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/include.html

To make this easy to edit, add the include file as a solution item in VS.